# Eclipse CDT MinGW toolchain: how to link with a library that does not begin with lib prefix?

Tags: c, mingw, eclipse-cdt

I have problems with linking to a library called `xyz.a` in my Eclipse CDT MinGW project. Eclipse projects cannot find this library unless I rename it to `libxyz.a`.

I have added:

- library path to project via `Properties/C C++ General/Paths and Symbols/Library Paths`.
- library name to project via `Properties/C C++ General/Paths and Symbols/Libraries`. Library name I specified here is `xyz`, so it's without extesion. What should I specify here in order to successfully include `xyz.a` without having to rename it to `libxyz.a`?

Some info I found online:

```
How do I specify the libraries to be searched by the linker?

    MinGW supports libraries named according to the "<name>.lib" and "<name>.dll" conventions, in addition to the normal "lib<name>.a" convention common on *nix systems. To include libraries named according to any of these conventions, simply add an associated "-l<name>" specification to the compiler command, ensuring it is placed after the name of the module in which the reference appears.
    Note that, if the library is not found in any of the default library search paths, you may also need to insert an appropriate "-L<dir>" switch to specify its location; (it is recommended that you place the "-L<dir>" switch before the "-l<name>" specification which requires it).
    Also note that the library names "lib<name>.a" and "lib<name>.lib" are not equivalent; if you have a library named according to the aberrant "lib<name>.lib" convention, it will not be found by an "-l<name>" specification -- if you cannot rename the library, you must use the form "-llib<name>" instead.
```

Comment: Do you read the doc you write here? "in addition to the normal "lib<name>.a" convention common on *nix systems."

Comment: Just include the library file in the list of files in the project.

Comment: @Stargateur What do you suggest? Anything except to rename the file to `libxyz.a` did NOT work. (And I cannot leave it renamed.)

Comment: _if you cannot rename the library, you must use the form "-llib<name>" instead_ what is not clear?

Comment: @Danijel Why you can't rename it? Library in this format **must** begin by "lib" and finish by ".a". If your project generate a wrong library name, fix it. They are no reason to keep "xyz.a" because you will have this problem in **ALL** your future project with this library.

Comment: It's a 3rd party library I am using...

Comment: @LPs I don't see where in the Eclipse I can specify this. All I can do is provide path and lib name, and IDE then generates linker switches.

Comment: @Danijel So you must send an issue to this 3rd party... they obviously need to fix it.

Comment: or get rid of cdt and use your own makefile or, not good  but not so bad, switch to autotools.

Comment: A bad workaround is to manually compile the fake lib into a simple makefile project to have a lib<name>.a file.

Comment: Yes, I'll try to send the issue to 3rd party, in the meantime I'll use the solution from the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can link a library called `oddname` - where `oddname` includes any file-extension - in Eclipse CDT like this:

- Navigate in the project **Properties** -> **C/C++ Build** -> **Settings**
  -> **Tool Settings** -> **GCC C++ Linker** -> **Libraries**.
- In **Libraries(-l)** panel add `:oddname`
- If necessary, in the **Library search path(-L)** panel add the path to
  `oddname`
- OK out

This setting will add the option `-l:oddname` to the generated GCC link
command. `-l:filename` is the form of the `-l` option signifying that
the conventional `lib` prefix and the `{.so|.a}` extension are *not* implied and that
`filename` is the actual filename of the library to be linked. [Here is the documentation](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html)

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks very much. To make things clearer: first place a colon `:`, then a filename **with** extension included.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest option is to just add the library to the command line of GCC. To do this with CDT add the library (whatever name it is) to the *Other object* (under Project settings -> *C/C++ Build* -> *GCC C Linker* -> *Miscellaneous*)

Here is a screenshot where I added a library with the file name `badname.a` to the command line of GCC.

[image]

When the build runs, this is the resultant command line:

```
Invoking: GCC C Linker
gcc  -o "SO"  ./src/SO.o  /home/me/workspace/SO/badname.a
```

**Note:** the disadvantage of the above solution is the whole library is included, not just the objects within it that are referenced. You can alternatively add *any* linker flags you want by adding them to the *Linker flags* box in the same dialog.